# Make Button Change Background

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have the following HTML code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="one">Button 1</button>
    <button id="two">Button 2</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I make the buttons change the background color from white to green or white to red and when reset is clicked make it change the background color back to white?

Comment: Using JS. Your question tags are HTML and CSS only. Is this to be done only via CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CSS only way but I wouldn't suggest using it. You need to have a div that takes up the entire body and contains all your content and have radio buttons to store the current state.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

[name=color] {
  display: none;
}

#green[name=color]:checked~.background {
  background: green;
}

#red[name=color]:checked~.background {
  background: red;
}

#white[name=color]:checked~.background {
  background: white;
}

.background {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.button {
  background-color: buttonface;
  padding: 2px 6px 3px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: buttonface;
}

.button:active {
  border-style: inset
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="color" id="green">
<input type="radio" name="color" id="red">
<input type="radio" name="color" id="white">

<div class="background">
  <label class="button" for="green">Green</label>
  <label class="button" for="red">Red</label>
  <label class="button" for="white">White</label>
</div>
```

This is just a basic implementation to make it viable you'd have to put in some aria stuff to make it A11y compliant.

Comment: Thank you for helping and sorry I have not been on for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want for the reset button but here a jQuery script that would do the job :

```js
$("#one").click(function() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "green");
});

$("#two").click(function() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "red");
});

$("#reset").click(function() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "white");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="one">Button 1</button>
<button id="two">Button 2</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

You can't do what you want with pure CSS

Here is a working fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/u66yann6/16/

Comment: OP didn't asked for jquery specifically. May be its better not to use it

Comment: @SankarshMakam yes? Is it what you want ?

Comment: I tested this in js fiddle and this is what it does: https://jsfiddle.net/u66yann6/

Comment: @JamesEstes delete the CSS and enable jQuery library, it works

Comment: It's not JS it's Jquery, change your description to avoid confusion

Comment: i love people who prefer asked than read simple doc before xD

Comment: I am wanting it to change the background of the website, not the button.

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud I think you meant to say `answer edited`. And why `$("body").css("background-color","white");` 2 times?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button data-color="blue">Button 1</button>
<button data-color="red">Button 2</button>
<button data-color="white">Reset</button>

...


$('[data-color]').click(function(){
    var color = $(this).data('color');
    $('body').css('background-color',color);
});
```

ultimate.

[jsfiddle.net/u66yann6/17](http://jsfiddle.net/u66yann6/17/)

Comment: try the new script and enjoy ! dont forgot to accept it :)=

Comment: Your script doesn't work @Pirs and Baptiste Arnaud already gave me a working code

Comment: The last one you gave me didn't

Comment: With the argument data-color you could change the background with every tags you want ;) trust me, avoid Id selector...